# Return object in array with specific property

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, function, foreach

I'm fairly new with writing my own JS functions, and I'm struggling with this one.

I want to run through an array of objects, find an object that matches a particular ID, and then return that object.

So far this is what I have:

```
var findTeam = function() {
  $scope.extraTeamData.forEach(team) {
     if(team.team_id === $scope.whichTeam) { return team }
  }
    $scope.thisTeam = team;
};
```

---

`$scope.teamDetails` is my array, and the `$scope.whichTeam` variable holds the correct ID which I am checking against.

Ultimately I want to be able to assign the object that results from the function to the `$scope.thisTeam` variable, so I can call its properties in the view.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: is there only one result?

Comment: Can you tell us what issue(s) you're experiencing with your current implementation?

Comment: Instead of `return team`, you could just do `$scope.thisTeam = team;`

Comment: Thanks Matt Burland - that trims it down a bit. I want to write it in the most efficient way possible, and to ultimately result in one variable which holds the desired object.

Comment: forEach requires a callback. your `forEach(team) {` is syntacticaly wrong. it should be `forEach(function (team) {` or if ES6 then `forEach(team => {`. and there is a missing closing parenteses.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which ends the iteration if found

```
var findTeam = function() {
    $scope.extraTeamData.some(function (team) {
        if (team.team_id === $scope.whichTeam) { 
            $scope.thisTeam = team;
            return true;
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: I put this into my controller in Angular and it broke the functionality altogether... :/

Comment: I think I may have a problem with my original array. Thanks though - your code has helped me to structure the function :)

Answer (score 1):

Move your `$scope.thisTeam = team;` to within the `if` check.

```
var findTeam = function() {
  $scope.teamDetails.forEach(team) {
     if(team.team_id === $scope.whichTeam) {
         $scope.thisTeam = team;
     }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.team = $scope.teamDetails.filter(function (team) {
  return team.team_id === $scope.whichTeam;
})[0];
```

You need to use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method of array. It creates new array elements that match given predicate (function that return boolean value). Then you simply take first value.

You can also use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), but it is not implemented in every browser yet.

It would look something like this:

```
$scope.team = $scope.teamDetails.find(function (team) {
  return team.team_id === $scope.whichTeam;
});
```